# How do I access these JavaScript member functions from outside?

Tags: javascript

I know how to access the below member function when it's written like this:

```
var blady_blah=
{
    some_member_function: function ()
    {
    }

}
```

I access it from outside doing `blady_blah.some_member_function()`

But how do I access the member function when it's written like this:

```
(function() {

    some_member_function: function ()
    {
    }

})();
```

Comment: you can't. that's a self-executing function.

Comment: That second example isn't valid syntax, either. Unexpected :

Comment: @Jason, I see. So any member functions I add there  will automatically execute as well?

Comment: @Ryan No, the member functions stay uninvoked until someone calls them. The only outcome from the above would be an error. You have a syntax error after `some_member_function` it should be an equals (=) sign and not a colon (:).

Answer (score 2):

Braces, { }, are used to define both object literals and function bodies. The difference is:

```
var name = {};    // Object literal
```

Which you may also see written as

```
var name = {

};
```

That's just the same but with some space in between so it's still an object literal, and unfortunately it looks very similar to:

```
var name = function () {    // Function body

};
```

An object can have members:

```
var name = {
  member: "string"
};
```

Whereas a function cannot; a function has statements:

```
var name = function () {
  do_something();
  var result = do_something_else();
};
```

You can't write

```
var name = function () {
  member: "string"
};
```

Because you've mixed the two uses of { } together.

A variable can be defined within a function, but it can't be seen outside the function - it's within the function scope:

```
var name = function () {
  var something_useful = string;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The second example is a closure (it just happens to have a syntax error inside).  Minus the bad syntax, your self-evaluating anonymous function looks like this:

```
(function() {
})();
```

If you'd like, you can define functions inside this that will be invisible to the outside world.  This is useful if you're interested in maintaining a clean global namespace, for example with library code.

```
(function() {
  function utilityFunctionFoo() {
  }

  function utilityFunctionBar() {
  }
})();
```

Of course, if you'd like to call any of these functions from the outside world, you're out of luck.  Or are you?  Actually, there's another way to define a function:

```
var foo = function() {
}
```

That's exactly the same as writing:

```
function foo() {
}
```

...Except that when written in the second style, you can actually omit the `var` keyword and create a global variable!  Bringing it all together:

```
(function() {
  publicData = "stuff accessible from outside anonymous function";
  var privateData = "stuff that stays inside anonymous function";

  function utilityFunctionFoo() {
  }

  function utilityFunctionBar() {
  }


  usefulFunctionExport = function() {
    utilityFunctionFoo();
    utilityFunctionBar();
  }
})();

usefulFunctionExport();
```

Comment: When i type `usefulFunctionExport=function() {` I get this error `Error: missing : after property`

Comment: @Ryan in my "bringing it together" example, pay special attention to the first line.  Does your script look like this, or are you simply using braces (which will create a associative array, not a closure).  As explained in other answers, associative arrays (aka object literals) and anonymous functions are two different beasts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it after the function it's in terminates.  It's a local variable that goes out of scope when its parent function ends.

You should make the main function be a constructor so that it returns a new instance of a class (you could name it Blahdy_blah) with the member function as one of its properties.

Look up constructors, their return values, and accessing member variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the function you need to return an object that exposes the function.

```
var LIB = (function() {

    var fn = {
        member_function : function(){}
    };

    return fn;


})();
```

and to call

```
LIB.member_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {

    blady_blah.some_member_function();

})();
```

If you need to add stuff into it you would write it like this.

```
(function() {

    blady_blah.some_member_function(function(){

        // Do stuff...

    });

})();
```